# Order of ${\rm Aut}(G)$ given $G$ is abelian group of order $30$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, automorphism-group

Since $G$ is abelian of order $30$ we have that $$G \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$$
$$\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}) = p-1, \text{ p prime} $$
does that mean $$|\text{Aut}(G)| = 1\cdot2\cdot4 = 8$$
or is it false that
$$\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}) \cong \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \times \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}) \times \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})$$

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843266/computing-operatornameautg-of-a-given-abelian-group?rq=1) for problems arising if two primes or coincide, i.e., are not coprime.